# Spell Checker for Search in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, full-text-search, freetext

I am building a search where I need to implement couple of features in it among others.

1- It should bring all synonyms, like if someone searches for couch, it should bring in matching results for that couch plus linguistic matches like (sofas, cushions etc). To accomplish that I am using Full Text Search.

In my query I use FreeText but it does not yield the required results. That's what I do,

```
select * from Furn_Products Where FreeText(FurnName, 'Couch');
```

It should bring Names containing Cushions, Sofa and Couch off course but it only brings Names with Couch which I could also do by simple Like query. Any solutions?

2- I need to check for typos, like if someone types `soofa`, it should bring in results for sofa, couch etc.

Any tips, ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nelson, there are lots of open-source search engines already out there, and they have gone through a lot of debugging.  The biggest ones are Lucene/Solr, Sphinx, and Xapian.

Also, be careful when adding synonym expansion.  If you expand **paddle**, for example, to **bat**, you might get a lot of zoological results you don't want.  If you're doing automated queries. find some examples and set up a test suite with corner cases.  If you expect to have human users, find a couple who will walk you through their processes to help build your test suite, and plan to get very friendly with the search logs.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Full Text Search doesn't give you access to all the possible words (stemming, etc.).  But starting with SQL Server 2008 you can get a list of all the indexed words.

For more features you would probably have to go with a 3rd party indexer like Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly define matches by [configuring the thesaurus](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345186%28SQL.90%29.aspx).